# Area-based job listings

Tags: feature-request, jobs, advertising

I have noticed that the job listings on Stack Overflow for me only show European ads (seeing as I'm European that's kinda nice) - however this is only *after* I've actually clicked to go to the list, the small ads on the pages themselves are still mainly showing all the U.S. ones - wouldn't it be ideal to make these small ads that's scattered out everywhere area-based as well?

Comment: This is a good observation.

Comment: Heh well it just kept bugging me. I noticed the area based stuff a while ago and was like "that's nice now I don't have to scan them all with my eyes" - and since then I cannot yet remember seeing an ad listing from Europe on the site itself and it just bugged me.